# Работа с видеопотоком с помощью класса MediaCapture

Tags: c#, windows-8

Необходимо написать программу, которая обрабатывает видео. Подскажите, как создавать собственные эффекты для видео, видеопоток идет в реальном времени, и обработка должна быть тоже в реальном времени. (Видеопоток уже реализован)

В конечном итоге на видео надо наложить пространственную декомпозицию и временную фильтрацию.

Comment: Наверное, надо гуглить. А математику писать не на C#, на C/C++.